# Передача параметра в функцию

Tags: android

Как сделать так чтобы след. функция принимала только мои константы?

```
private void add(int type){

}
```

и где-то есть класс с константами

```
class types {
   int white = 1;
   int black = 2;
}
```

как сделать так чтобы функция add принимала только значения types?

пример:

```
 public abstract FragmentTransaction replace(@IdRes int containerViewId, Fragment fragment,
            @Nullable String tag);
```

В данном случае параметр containerViewId может быть только Id ресурса

Comment: использовать enum ?

Comment: Понял, спасибро

Comment: В Java принято говорить методы, а не функции.

Answer (score 1):

Ты это имеешь ввиду ?!

```
private void add(types type){
```

Comment: Не совсем. Вот пример:
 public abstract FragmentTransaction replace(@IdRes int containerViewId, Fragment fragment,
            @Nullable String tag);

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html